# How to clear cache image in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image, caching

I want to clear my cache in my application. Some times, my application get crashed due to some memory warning like,

```
      Received memory warning. Level=1

      Received memory warning. Level=2
```

In my application, i have used asynchronous method and downloading image in cache and displayed in the view. so how can i clear the image cache. how do i solve this problem.

Please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: How would you store those cached images? in your own NSArray?

Comment: Pugal Devan: Have u any found any solution for this!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images you have downloaded my be of big size,That's why its causing the error "Memory warning ".Try using the image of very less size.

All the Best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its very helpful for me. And also check the image resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are getting memory warning kindly do this, clear all cached images or part of cached images from application. For do that you can use two places,
 1. In application delegate class: - (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
2. In your view controller, -(void) didReceiveMemoryWarning